# why does console.log show different description

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, declaration

I run the following in node: why does the first console.log show:

```
greet: [Function],
```

and the second console.log show:

```
greet: [Function: greet]
```

Is there any difference? (note, console.log in chrome doesn't show the difference)

```js
function deepCopy(obj){

/* an object has key value pairs
   check if val is object
   if true deepCopy(val)
   else return value            */

   const keys = Object.keys(obj); // gets keys of object
   const newObject = {}

   for(index in keys){
      if(typeof(obj[keys[index]]) === 'object') {
    newObject[keys[index]] = deepCopy(obj[keys[index]])
      }else{
    newObject[keys[index]] = obj[keys[index]]
      }
  }
   return newObject
}

o={
name:'David',
teach:true,
obj:{
     greet:function(){
           console.log('hi!')},
     last:'cross'
    }
}



o2 = deepCopy(o)


o.obj.greet=function(){
     console.log('bye')}


o.name='george'

console.log(o)
console.log(o2)

o.obj.greet()
o2.obj.greet()
```

Comment: Both should show [Function: greet] (see [Inferred function names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name#Inferred_function_names)). If it doesn't it's probably a browser quirk.

Answer (score 0):

1. When you declare the method `{ great:function(){} }`, it will have a `.name` and will be print out by `console.log`. Even you pass it around (assign to `o2` via `deepCopy`), it will keep it name.
2. When you create an anonymous function `function(){}`, it's `.name` is empty. which you assign it to `o.great = function(){}`.

I create a simplify version to explain op question to test.

```js
const a = { great: function(){}  }; // in object declaration, method great as name "great" (x)
const b = {};
b.great = function(){}; // b.great is point to an anonymous function with no name (y)
// When console.log a function, if function has name, it will show out
console.log("a.great", a.great);
console.log("b.great", b.great);
console.log("a.great.name", JSON.stringify(a.great.name)); // "great"
console.log("b.great.name", JSON.stringify(b.great.name)); // "";

b.great = a.great; // simliar when you deep copy o2 from o
// in this case, b.great is point to the method great (x)
// so when you log out the name, it will print out
console.log("b.great.name", JSON.stringify(b.great.name)); // "great"

a.great = function(){}; // similar when o.great get re-assign
// a.great got re-assign to an anonymous function with no name (z)
// so when you log out the name, it will print out ""
console.log("a.great.name", JSON.stringify(a.great.name)); // ""

// Finally:
console.log(a.great);
console.log(b.great);
```

Comment: This is not an answer. OP is asking **why** it happens. He's not asking for a workaround or replacement code.

Comment: @GreatBigBore  I mean want to explain the question, not a workaround. I have updated to make it clear. Thank for the feedback.

Comment: That doesn't explain anything. it's just a bunch of examples. **Why** does Javascript treat `a` and `b` differently? That's the question. You're not answering it.

Comment: i guess will never know

Comment: Seems like the answer is updated with an explanation now